# Primitive to String typing fails with T extends null...?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a primitive to a string representation, and I've distilled it down to the following code:

```js
type arg = string | boolean | number | Date | null;

type PrimToString<T> =
    | T extends string ? 'string' : never
    | T extends boolean ? 'boolean' : never
    | T extends number ? 'number' : never
    | T extends Date ? 'date' : never
    | T extends null ? 'null' : never
;

const a: PrimToString<arg> = 'string';   // Good
const b: PrimToString<arg> = 'boolean';  // Good
const c: PrimToString<arg> = 'number';   // Good
const d: PrimToString<arg> = 'date';     // Good
const e: PrimToString<arg> = 'null';     // Shows Error (below)

var a = 'string';
var b = 'boolean';
var c = 'number';
var d = 'date';
var e = 'null';

// Type '"null"' is not assignable to type '"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "date"'.
```

It's surprising that `'null'` isn't displayed at all, even when hovering, say, `const c`.

Here is a [Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20arg%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20Date%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PrimToString%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20T%20extends%20string%20%3F%20'string'%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20T%20extends%20boolean%20%3F%20'boolean'%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20T%20extends%20number%20%3F%20'number'%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20T%20extends%20Date%20%3F%20'date'%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20T%20extends%20null%20%3F%20'null'%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20PrimToString%3Carg%3E%20%3D%20'string'%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20PrimToString%3Carg%3E%20%3D%20'boolean'%3B%0D%0Aconst%20c%3A%20PrimToString%3Carg%3E%20%3D%20'number'%3B%0D%0Aconst%20d%3A%20PrimToString%3Carg%3E%20%3D%20'date'%3B%0D%0Aconst%20e%3A%20PrimToString%3Carg%3E%20%3D%20'null'%3B) that demonstrates the issue.

Anyone think this is a bug?  How should I type this differently?

Answer (score 4):

When `strictNullChecks` is disabled (which is the case by default), `null` is a special value that can be assigned to any of these values. Observe:

```
const str: string = null;
```

This is fine when `strictNullChecks` is disabled, but when enabled, it will generate

> Type '`null`' is not assignable to type '`string`'.

Similarly:

```
type A = null extends string ? true : false;
```

Will yield `true` when `strictNullChecks` is disabled, and `false` when enabled.

So when `strictNullChecks` is disabled, `string | boolean | number | Date | null` is fully equivalent to `string | boolean | number | Date`, and your `PrimToString<T>` type will never hit the final union case. Enabling this compiler option will allow your code to work as expected.

See [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug you just have the wrong compiler settings. Under default settings, `null` is assignable to any other type, so it will get simplified in the union. If you activate `strictNullChecks` then the code works as expected: [Link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgTgcygXigZ2HAlgOyQHygCMB7EgGwhhykJwFcBbIiOWqAERmGjvvPIBuAFDDQkKAAVsjACokAyplwIAPLIB8KYVF3tZUCAA8eOACZp0yvFAD8UAOQZseB1ABcUHBABurHXqEBsamFsRklNR2jqQUVDhunt5+cAG6QYYmEOaWDMys0Q55LHCJXr7+evqZoZZcPIVm3BBlyZWBUMFZOV785IUMAq0VqSLCAMYkOBiwntJYcorWavAIWqhOyw4ik9PAxHMy8kouK4jrMRHx2xNTM+OHC8fLqqsXRUwlN7szZo+LJxUr3OKEcTR43zu+wg-2ep2Ba1BHyGgiAA)